# org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from resource *.hbm.xml

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, maven, many-to-one

I know this question has been asked a lot, but I read almost every one of them but non of them helped me.
I'm writing an eclipse maven project with hibernate and I'm getting this error:

```
org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from resource ir/ac/ut/ieproj/da/Student.hbm.xml
```

my files are like this:

pom.xml

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>ir.ac.ut</groupId>
  <artifactId>ieproj</artifactId>
  <version>0.2</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>ieproj</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

<build>

    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/java</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
      </resource>
    </resources>

   <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>

    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>

    </plugin>
   </plugins>

</build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>JBoss repository</id>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ir.ac.ut</groupId>
        <artifactId>iecommon</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.24</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1-Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1-Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.4-Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.4</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

</project>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db</property>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.password">13812002</property>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</property>
      <property name="show_sql">true</property>
      <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
      <!-- Mapping files -->
      <mapping resource="ir/ac/ut/ieproj/da/Department.hbm.xml"/>
      <mapping resource="ir/ac/ut/ieproj/da/Studyrec.hbm.xml"/>
      <mapping resource="ir/ac/ut/ieproj/da/Student.hbm.xml"/>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Department.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="ir.ac.ut.ieproj.da">
    <class name="DepartmentRepo" table="department">
              <id name="id" type="int" column="ID" >
                <generator class="assigned"/>           
              </id>
              <property name="name" column="Name" type="string"/>
    </class>

    <sql-query name="getDeptName">
        <return alias="Department" class="DepartmentRepo"/>
        <![CDATA[select * from db.department d where d.ID = :id]]>
    </sql-query>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

Student.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="ir.ac.ut.ieproj.da">
    <class name="StudentRepo" table="student">
              <id name="id" type="int" column="ID" >
                <generator class="assigned"/>           
              </id>
              <property name="firstName" type="string" column="FirstName" />
              </property>
              <property name="lastName" type="string" column="LastName"/>
              </property>
              <property name="program" type="string" column="Program"/>
              </property>
              <many-to-one
                name="dept"
                class="DepartmentRepo"
                cascade="all"
                not-null="true"
                column="deptId"/>
    </class>

    <sql-query name="findStudentId">
        <return alias="Student" class="StudentRepo"/>
        <![CDATA[select * from db.student s where s.ID = :sid]]>
    </sql-query>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

StudentRepo.java

```
package ir.ac.ut.ieproj.da;

import ir.ac.ut.ieproj.model.Student;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.MappingException;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

public class StudentRepo {

    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String program;
    private DepartmentRepo dept;

    public Student getStudentbyId (String sid) throws MappingException, HibernateException, Exception {

        Student student = new Student();
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getHibernateSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        Query query = session.getNamedQuery("findStudentId").setLong("sid", Long.valueOf(sid));
        StudentRepo studentRepo = (StudentRepo) query.uniqueResult();
        student.setId(studentRepo.getId());
        student.setFirstName(studentRepo.getFirstName());
        student.setLastName(studentRepo.getLastName());
        student.setProgram(Integer.valueOf(studentRepo.getProgram()));
        tx.commit();
        session.close();

        return student;

    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getProgram() {
        return program;
    }

    public void setProgram(String program) {
        this.program = program;
    }

    public DepartmentRepo getDept() {
        return dept;
    }

    public void setDept(DepartmentRepo dept) {
        this.dept = dept;
    }

}
```

DepartmentRepo.java

```
package ir.ac.ut.ieproj.da;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.MappingException;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

import ir.ac.ut.ieproj.model.Department;

public class DepartmentRepo {

    private int id;
    private String name;

    public Department getDeptbyId(String id) throws MappingException, HibernateException, Exception {

        Session session = HibernateUtil.getHibernateSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        Query query = session.getNamedQuery("getDeptName").setLong("id", Integer.valueOf(id));
        DepartmentRepo departmentRepo = (DepartmentRepo) query.uniqueResult();
        Department department = new Department();
        department.setName(departmentRepo.getName());
        tx.commit();
        session.close();

        return department;

    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

I think the problem is with the many-to-one tag in Student.hbm.xml because Department.hbm.xml and the namedQuery within are not causing an error. What am I doing wrong? I'm using mvn package to make a .war file and then deploy it in tomcat 7.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error `Could not parse mapping document` is about your xml files **not** being well-formed. When this error comes up, we'd better double check our xml files to see if they are really OK (all tags are properly closed and so on).

---

In your case, as the message states, your `Student.hbm.xml` file is the problem. You have some tags that do not belong:

```
<property name="firstName" type="string" column="FirstName" />
</property> <------------------------------------------------------ remove this
<property name="lastName" type="string" column="LastName"/>
</property> <------------------------------------------------------ remove this
<property name="program" type="string" column="Program"/>
</property> <------------------------------------------------------ remove this
```

Those closing `</property>` tags aren't closing no one, as the `<property` tags above them are self-closed (notice the `/>`).

Comment: I guessed its about the file and the syntax, so I checked it 20 times but couldn't find any error. Guess a second person was needed to check it for me, thanks

Comment: dtd can be also issue. Change DTD into http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd

Answer (score 2):

Try to change hibernate mapping DTD.
My problem solves after changing 
http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd 
to 
http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd

Comment: This solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

May Be This problem because of Not matching  with The variable names used in bean class.

For eg.
Then Your variable names should be FirstName.

Answer (score 0):

In my case was just a comment at the beggining of xml.
If someone have a comment like  just remove it and maybe will work.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove `<?xml version="1.0"?>` from your mapping and config file.It will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

you might have configured multiple times of mapping tag for same entity/persistence.

Answer (score 0):

My problem solves after changing http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd to http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd.  The issue could caused by timeout when access to remote DTD file.

I would download the hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd and make it available locally.

Answer (score 0):

I had such an error when the file - .hbm.xml - started not from the first line, but from the second. The first was just empty.

Answer (score -1):

You just close your property like

```
<property name="firstName" type="string" column="FirstName" />
```

or

```
<property name="firstName" type="string" column="FirstName"></property>
```